# VBA how do i move an image to the next page in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm importing a bunch of images into a word file, but i want to move each image onto a seperate page.
Unfortunately "pages(x).inlineshapes.cut" or something similar wouldn't work because "pages" is not recognised.

i've tried the folowing, but this obviously won't work.

```
    If Activepage.InlineShapes.Count <> 0 Then
    Pages(i).InlineShapes(i).Cut
    k = i + 1
    ActiveDocument.pages(k).Activate
    Selection.Paste
    End If
```

Comment: Your code is not clear how Word is supposed to find these images. If you're trying to make a document like a photo album, you can use a batch process to import a folder full of images, adding a page break after each image. This will create 1 page per image. Search on _Word vba batch process image import_ for sample code.

Comment: Format the paragraph containing each image with Page Break Before formatting. Then add a paragraph break after the image. See https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html and https://addbalance.com/word/MovePages.htm#PageStart